# How to merge an xsl node into a another xml result tree using xsl:for-each instead of apply-templates or match-template

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to use the xsl:for-each to merge two xml nodes into a single result tree.These two are stored in a variable in my application.

node 1:

```
<request>
    <package>
        <packageType>BONSHO</packageType>
        <price>P1</price>
    </package>
</request>
```

node 2:

```
 <root>
    <fareGroups>
        <fareGroup>
            <fareCode>BEST</fareCode>
        </fareGroup>
    </fareGroups>
    <fareGroups>
        <fareGroup>
            <fareCode>DRINKS</fareCode>
        </fareGroup>
    </fareGroups>
</root>
```

Expected output

```
<request>
    <package>
        <packageType>BONSHO</packageType>
        <fareGroups>
            <fareGroup>
                <fareCode>BEST</fareCode>
            </fareGroup>
        </fareGroups>
        <fareGroups>
            <fareGroup>
                <fareCode>DRINKS</fareCode>
            </fareGroup>
        </fareGroups>
        <price>P1</price>
    </package>
</request>
```

I cannot use  to iterate over the first node and then select the second nodes and merge it.
I'm trying to merge them using . Is that possible ?

Comment: i meant I cannot use "template match" and instead have to use only "for-each" to achieve this.

Comment: "*These two are stored in a variable in my application.*" This part is not clear.

Comment: The application has these node 1 and node 2 stored them in a xsl variable.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You tagged this question as XSLT. There is no "application" in XSLT.  Please provide a **reproducible** problem - see: [mcve].